# Hammerspoon - how to paste text?

Tags: macos, hammerspoon

I can't find it in the docs - how do i paste text with Hammerspoon on OS X?

I tried the following:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"ctrl", "pad1"}, "1", function()
    hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("this needs to be pasted!")
end)
```

but it does not work.

I pressed "control" and Numpad's "1" on my keyboard.

Thanks for help!

Comment: i used AutoHotKey on Windows!

Answer (score 4):

I found out how it works, the keybinding was wrong.

```
hs.hotkey.bind(
    {"ctrl"}, "Pad1", function()
        hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("asd") end
    )
```

Thank you all for helping.